# How does lazy-loading (router) come into play with A Nativescript app?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I'm trying to understand something fundamental here.

With a web app - when I use - Lazy loading modules via router - the module is loaded via ajax request from the server and moves on.

But what about Native web app ( Nativescript) ? I mean - assuming the app doesn't use internet connection - where will he get the lazy modules from ?

Which means that all modules must be in the APK file. and that APK should be fully loaded in order for the app to run.

**Question**

How is it considered to be lazy module loaded in a NativeScript app - where  the APK file must fully be loaded at first place ? ( without internet connection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think I understand what you are asking.

Lazy loading isn't that something is loaded from the internet. It's (just) when something is loaded when it's needed, it doesn't matter if it's from disk or the internet.

Lazy loading with nativescript-angular is mostly about startup time.
Usually you don't need all your components at the startup, so loading them when needed will make the app start faster. (At least in theory, I haven't had time to use it yet.)

According to this article: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/optimizing-app-loading-time-with-angular-2-lazy-loading

Nexus 5 -> Start up without lazy load: 13s, with "just" 4s.

Comment: Analogy to windows : say you load a 16mb exe. the app will be visible only when all 16mb were read and loaded. so what lazy in here ?

Comment: The part where the rest of the code is in another 32mb file.

Comment: But there is no other APK that you download nor nothing is downloaded . So I don't understand

Comment: I think I see the confusion now :) The APK file is "just" an archive for distribution, you can open it in a unzipper and see the content. In a nativescript APK, you'll find some native-.so-files from nativescript and modules you've added and some JS-files. vendor.js and bundle.js in the default way of bundling. vendor.js is js-libraries and bundle.js is mostly your js-code.

Comment: So the APK-zip-alike contains a modules files which will be loaded as necessary ?

Comment: Yes. You could try building this https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng and looking at the APK-file.

Comment: Thank you........ ( btw - are those files in js you mentioned - are compiled at runtime ? IMHO - that's not the case , and I might be wrong).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159478/discussion-between-mabs-and-royi-namir).